# Always call a binary with a specific flag in linux

Tags: linux, command

I was wondering if there is any way to execute a binary in linux, always with a specific flag.

For example, whenever `genisoimage` executes, I want it always executes with `-allow-limited-size` flag. So, issuing the `genisoimage` in console, results in `genisoimage -allow-limited-size` run.

`alias` won't work as the binary is called from another one

Comment: Have you looked into the [alias](http://ss64.com/bash/alias.html) command?

Comment: alias won't work as the binary is called from another one.

Comment: Why does your question not mention that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep! What you're looking for is a Bash `alias`.

Just add `alias genisoimage="genisoimage -allow-limited-size"` to your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.bash_profile` for macOS) file.

For more info on the Bash alias, check out http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html?cachebusterTimestamp=1466192028407

**EDIT: Given that another script or application calls `genisoimage`.**

If it's being called form another script or application, you're going to have to change the `genisoimage` that's resolved within that script/application. Here's how you may be able to accomplish this.

First, Create your own `genisoimage` which adds your `-allow-limited-size` flag. This will go in to a file named `genisoimage` at `/some/other/path` and must be made executable (i.e. `chmod u+x /some/other/path/genisoimage`). Suppose that the genuine `genisoimage` file is located at `/bin/genisoimage`

```
#! /bin/bash
/bin/genisoimage -allow-limited-size "$@"
```

The above adds the desired flag, and passes all arguments along to the origin `genisoimage`.

Now when you run your script/application, change the `PATH` variable so the file you just created is found first.

```
$> PATH=/some/other/path:$PATH ./APPLICATION
```

Comment: The problem is that the binary is called internally from another application.

Comment: @Vahid I just updated my answer to take that into account.

Comment: Thanks @Joshua, so there is not way that with the combination of soft links and alias I can do that, right?

Comment: I think it depends on how much control you have over the "application" or "script" that's calling `genisoimage`. You may also be able to just use a variable in that script (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/98782/how-to-run-an-alias-in-a-shell-script?cachebusterTimestamp=1466194408680). But, it seems like you don't have that control (given the question) so something like I've outlined above is the best I can come up with.